# Is it possible to perform the following calculation in pine script?

Tags: pine-script, trading

Dear pine script experts!

I wonder if it possible to perform the following calculation in pine script:

**[volatility(month, specific ticker)/change in % (day, specific ticker)]  /  [volatility(month, current ticker)/change in % (day, current ticker)]**

Volatility (month) can be selected in the Tradingview Screener. If this resource cannot be used in pine script, I assume that the same quotient could be calculated in the following way.

**[atr(20) of a specific ticker)/absolute change (day, specific ticker)]  /  [atr(20) of the current ticker)/absolute change (day, current ticker)]**

I am a newbie in pince script and programming in general and getting stuck here. It would be great if someone here could help me out.

So: (1) Can the one of both formula be calculated in pine script *at all?* And (2) if so, can someone briefly *explain to me how to implement* this? I would be so ***GRATEFUL*** for an answer!

Quuh

**Intermediate result**:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Volatility-Adjusted RS", shorttitle="VA-RS", overlay=false, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

//Input
length = input.int(title="Length", defval=20, minval=1)
benchmark = input.symbol("NASDAQ:QQQ", title="Benchmark")

//Functions
atr_rma_function(security, length) =>
_high = request.security(security, timeframe.period, high)
_low = request.security(security, timeframe.period, low)
_close = request.security(security, timeframe.period, close)
trueRange = math.max(math.abs(_high - _close[1]), math.abs(_close[1]-_low))
ta.rma(trueRange, length)

//Calcs
benchMarkATR = atr_rma_function(benchmark, length)
benchMarkChange = math.abs(ta.change(request.security(benchmark, timeframe.period, close), length))

symbolATR = ta.atr(length)
symbolChange = math.abs(ta.change(close, length))

rs = (symbolATR/symbolChange) / (benchMarkATR/benchMarkChange) - 1
plot(rs)
hline(0)`
```

Unfortunately, the result is not satisfactory, because I actually expected the outputs to fluctuate around zero, but they do not. Can anybody explain to me what I did wrong, or better yet, how I can solve the problem? I am desperate!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Both possible. For [1], you need to create a function for volatility. In general, there is already a built-in function called `atr()`. For the change, you can easily calculate that yourself or there is also `change()` function. If you need to refer to other timeframes, then you must use the `security()` function.

Have a look at all those, I would start with [2] as it is easier.

Comment: This is awesome news! I will then have a look into the functions mentioned and hopefully be able to create a formula. May I come back to you again in case of queries?

Best regards

Comment: Of course, this is why we are here. If you found my comment helpful, I can convert it to an answer with maybe a couple of more details. At first I thought you want us to write the code for you which is NOT why we are here :)

Comment: Great! This could be the start of a really super useful tool for my trading. If you think you can help me with some more info, don't hesitate to share. But my goal is to write the script myself as much as possible. However, the formula made/makes me considerable problems. Ideally, I will be able to work on it tomorrow. I'll get back to you with the result, if I may!

Comment: Hi vitruvius, The **above code** is the intermediate result for my script. Unfortunately, the result is not satisfactory, because I actually expected the outputs to fluctuate around zero, but they do not. Can you or someone else explain to me what I did wrong, or better yet, how I can solve the problem?